# Как сделать тернарный if на JS?

Tags: javascript

Условие если А меньше B то увеличить A на 1, в противном случае не делать ничего.

```
// не работает, синтаксическая
(A < B) ? A++ : ;

// не работает, синтаксическая
(A < B) ? A++;
```

Больше нет идей, так вообще можно? Может быть можно

```
(A < B) ? A++ : A = A;
```

Но не уверен будет ли это корректно?

Comment: Напишите 2 раза ;;

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka не работает...

Comment: A=(A<B)?A+1:A //тернарный

Comment: Почему не воспользоваться инструкцией If?

Comment: A=(A < B) ? ++A:A;
тоже можно. Инкремент префиксный.

Comment: Задача _"если А меньше B, то увеличить A на 1"_ решается с помощью `if`. Использование тернарного оператора тут неуместно

Comment: @user258184 может вы не знаете, надо ставить галочку у ответов, которые показались полезными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То как Вы хотите:

```
(A < B) ? A++ : 0;
```

Еще короче:

```
A < B && A++
```

Но, вроде бы, в последнее время как раз приходят к тому, что лучше так не писать - не должно вычисление выражения создавать "побочные эффекты".

Классический скучный вариант:

```
if (A < B) A++
```

Обратите внимание, не так много места занимает. У Вас же символы, надеюсь, не платные.

Answer (score 4):

Тернарный оператор используют, чтобы **вычислить значение** в зависимости от логического значения. 
Поэтому лучше написать

```
A=(A<B)?A+1:A
```

Comment: Лучше написать `if`. Тернарный оператор тут неуместен, и, как следствие, `: A` - является уже костылём

Comment: Автор, наверное, сам бы написал с if. Но вопрос был в том, как написать тернарным, и чтобы пропустил компилятор, а он понятия уместен не знает. Пропустил - хорошо.

Comment: @Regent  "костыль" вот так console.log(a<b ? a+1 : a); сработает, а **if** - нет.

Comment: @tilin а как ваш пример связан с данным вопросом, в котором речь идёт об увеличении значения переменной `a` на единицу?

Comment: @Regent  ну так вопрос был о том, как сделать тетрарный оператор, а не просто увеличить значение по условию. А пример показывает, что if и тетрарный оператор имеют разные области применения. Возможно автору вопроса следовало более четко сформировать вопрос.

Comment: @tilin вопрос звучит примерно как "Как использовать микроскоп для забивания гвоздя?". А я продолжаю настаивать, что для забивания гвоздей нужно использовать молоток, а не пытаться взять микроскоп таким образом, чтобы получилось им забить гвоздь.

Comment: Тернарный оператор это краткая форма условного оператора, поэтому аналогия неуместна, он гвоздь забивает топором, а это не так страшно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно на CoffeeScript:

```
A++ if A < B
```